# Is eval implemented by creating a shell process to evaluate the following command?

Tags: bash, eval

In `eval <command>`, how does `eval` evaluate the following command?

- does `eval` create a shell subprocess to evaluate `<command>`?
- If not, does `eval` rely on the current shell process to evaluate it?

Note that

- `eval` is a builtin, so there is no subprocess created for `eval` itself.
- Right before `<command>` is executed, there may or may not be a subprocess created to run it, depending on whether `<command>` isn't a builtin.

The shell subprocess to evaluate the command mentioned above isn't either of the two mentioned in the note.

Thanks.

Answer (score 5):

What `eval` effectively does is parse the arguments, expanding variables etc etc and then the resulting string is executed as normal.

So, for example:

```
$ i=ls
$ eval $i
```

The `eval` here will replace `$i` with `ls` and *then* run the `ls` command as normal (so it will `fork()`/`exec()` to run the `ls` process).

If, however you did

```
$ i="echo hello"
$ eval $i
hello
```

then no new process is created because the `echo hello` is run as a builtin.

We can see no shell is created by setting variables:

```
$ a=0
$ i="a=100"
$ eval $i
$ echo $a
100
```

`$a` could only be set to 100 if that was done in the current shell.

So the `eval` itself is really just a parser and is done in the current shell; the *results* of that string may or may not create a new process, same as any other command.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know about underneath, but in practice, it runs it just like `source somefile`, where it just runs these commands in your current shell process, without spawning a new process.

And also I'd use the word "string" rather than "commands", since that's what it does. This works, but has no command:

```
$ eval ""
```

Or this which is not technically a command:

```
$ eval "x(){ echo test;}"
$ x
test
```

And to show it's not always making a new process (so I disagree with William):

in one terminal:

```
$ echo $$
9983
$ eval "sleep 100"
```

in another:

```
$ ps -ef --forest
peter     9983  2840  0 14:21 pts/41   00:00:00  \_ /bin/bash
peter    17339  9983  0 14:26 pts/41   00:00:00  |   \_ sleep 100
```

But if you do this it does for some reason:

```
$ eval 'sleep 100' &
[1] 20675

$ ps --forest
  PID TTY          TIME CMD
 9983 pts/41   00:00:00 bash
20675 pts/41   00:00:00  \_ bash
20676 pts/41   00:00:00  |   \_ sleep
20757 pts/41   00:00:00  \_ ps
```

Comment: Sorry @peter, I am not following you. What I see is that it does create a new child process in both of your examples. So what you disagree with me?

Comment: @WillianPaixao In the `eval "sleep 100"` example, it created a sleep process, but not a bash process. And you can't see it, but in the `x()` example, where I ran no command, I believe but cannot prove it didn't make any process, only defined a function, and the function was then available in the original process, which implies it executed the string/script in the original.

Comment: Peter, @WillianPaixao : you can observe when new processes are created by running bash under `strace` (or your OS's equivalent if not running Linux) (`strace -f -o bash.strace bash`)

Comment: @Gilles good idea....why didn't I think of strace. And yes I can see it calls clone() for the sleep in background, but not for the other tests: `20172 clone(child_stack=0, flags=CLONE_CHILD_CLEARTID|CLONE_CHILD_SETTID|SIGCHLD, child_tidptr=0x71be36ad89d0) = 20269`

Answer (score 2):

Eval does not create a new process just for the purpose of `eval`.

Eval rather re-runs the parser with a concatenation of the `eval`-arguments.

The result of this parsing is then run in the same shell. If the arguments however require to create a sub-shell for the command this is done.

So the main purpose of eval is to re-run the parser.

Answer (score 0):

Try this one: the `$$` between `''` expands during the eval, the `$$` between `""` before the eval:

```
$ eval /bin/echo '$$' "$$"
17899 17899
```

So as both are expanded in the same process, there is no subshell started by eval. Note that I took the non-shell-function echo.

Comment: Not that it changes anything, but since `echo "$$"` and `( echo "$$" )`  would output the same number, you many want to show your example with a variable whose value is actually different in a subshell, i.e. `$BASHPID`.